# T4 не видит пространство имен

Tags: c#, visual-studio, t4

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ import namespace="System" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

namespace TestApp
{
<#
    var type = Type.GetType("TestApp.MyClass", false);
    var typeName = type == null ? "Null" : type.Name;
#>
    public partial class <#= typeName #>
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

В сгенерированный класс попадает `Null`
Подскажите почему не видит?

Comment: А какую логику вы хотите реализовать? Сейчас логика выглядит так: если в вашем коде есть класс `TestApp.MyClass`, то создать его снова. Это не похоже на правильную логику.

Comment: @VladD, почему создать? он же partial

Comment: @Grundy: Если класс генерируется кодом на Т4, он должен знать, что он генерирует, а не подглядывать в будущий ответ.

Comment: @VladD, так он ж типа расширения генерирует

Comment: @VladD это просто в качестве примера. А вообще хотел пройтись по некоторым методам классов из пространства и добавить асинхронные аналоги. Получается нужно все регулярками?

Comment: @VladD впрочем да, пройдусь регулярками. Спасибо за ответ)

Comment: T4 может получить доступ к типам из уже скомпилированной сборки (dll).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да, использовал для сборок `<#@ assembly name="Name" #>`, но тут так не получалось

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Но эта информация будет всё время запаздывать на один шаг.

Comment: @Skrim: Можно положить текст метода в T4 и генерировать оба метода одновременно. Тем не менее, сама идея кажется мне сомнительной: [(1)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/), [(2)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/04/13/should-i-expose-synchronous-wrappers-for-asynchronous-methods/).

Comment: Впрочем: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16962822/276994. Но создавать циклическую зависимость — плохая идея.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что T4 бежит не в контексте вашего приложения, а в своём собственном. Соответственно в контексте выполнения T4 нету типа `TestApp.MyClass`, и `Type.GetType` не может найти его.

T4 — это не ваше приложение, это код, который *создаёт текст* вашего приложения.

Comment: ну так написал бы как сделать, чтобы заработало :-)

Comment: @Grundy: По нормальному никак, ведь код приложения на этом этапе только создаётся, так что компиляция ещё не произошла и типа ещё нету.

Comment: А если по не нормальному?

Comment: @Grundy: Я как lawful good плохих советов дать не могу :-)